# Simpsons Integral or the like for Integrating over Triangular Surfaces

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I have several triangles in 3D space where I know the value of the function at the three vertices of the triangle (Could be determined in between at any point as well). I wanted to know if there exists any numerical technique to get the integral for this function over the triangular surface.

Comment: By point here I meant that the function can be computed in between the triangle as well since we would know the x,y,z values there.  For eg at its circumcenter or any other arbitrary location. It does not mean any further subdivision of the domain.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood the goal. It's _not_ about the triangles' surface. My bad.

Comment: If your vertices are $V_0, V_1, V_2$, then define $r(x,y) = V_0 + x(V_1 - V_0) + y(V_2 - V_0)$, then use any 2D integration technique to integrate $f\circ r$ over the triangle bounded by $x = 0, y = 0, x + y = 1$. Multiply that result by $\frac12\|(V_1 - V_0) \times (V_2 - V_0)\|$ to get the integral you are after.